# TargetPath не соответствует значению свойства выходного файла для Linker

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Всем добрый день! Пытаюсь запустить программу в Visual Studio 2017 исходники программы на гитхабе по этой ссылке https://github.com/viruscamp/luadec . Но возникает ошибка. Как я понял программа написана на 2008 студио и при обновлении что то сбивается и перестает работать. Помогите исправить ошибку. Вот такое выдает в консоли.

```
 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1216,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(D:\decomp\luadec-master\luadec-master\vcproj-5.3\Debug\bin\luadll.dll) не соответствует значению свойства выходного файла (D:\decomp\luadec-master\luadec-master\vcproj-5.3\Debug\bin\lua53.dll) для Linker. Это может привести к неправильной сборке проекта. Чтобы исправить это, убедитесь, что значения свойств $(OutDir), $(TargetName) и $(TargetExt) соответствуют значению, указанному в %(Link.OutputFile).
    1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1218,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(luadll) не соответствует значению свойства выходного файла (lua53) для Linker. Это может привести к неправильной сборке проекта. Чтобы исправить это, убедитесь, что значения свойств $(OutDir), $(TargetName) и $(TargetExt) соответствуют значению, указанному в %(Link.OutputFile).
    1>lapi.obj : warning LNK4075: не учитывается "/EDITANDCONTINUE" из-за спецификации "/SAFESEH"
    1>   Создается библиотека D:\decomp\luadec-master\luadec-master\vcproj-5.3\Debug\bin\lua53.lib и объект D:\decomp\luadec-master\luadec-master\vcproj-5.3\Debug\bin\lua53.exp
    1>luadll.vcxproj -> D:\decomp\luadec-master\luadec-master\vcproj-5.3\Debug\bin\luadll.dll
    1>Сборка проекта "luadll.vcxproj" завершена.
```

Comment: Так там почти человеческим языком все расписано. Вы пробовали это все сделать?

Comment: @KoVadim К сожалению я еще не осваивал Visual Studio и просто не понимаю как это сделать...

Comment: "Не понимаю как это сделать" - не понимаете как прочитать, или что? :-O Там же все написано, причем даже по-русски.

Comment: У вас проект lua53, а в установках линкера имя выходного файла заменено на luadll, вот вас VS и предпреждает, что возможны проблемы. VS 2017 в отличие от 2008 к таким вещам относится немного истерично. Но dll у вас тем не менее успешно строится, так что вы сами решайте важно это для вас или нет.

Comment: @freim Теперь стало более понятно спасибо. Но программа не создает фаил luadll и в итоге при запуске выдает ошибку что luadll не найден. если переименовать файлы в папке с lua53 на luadll выводится ошибка что luadll.dll не является допустимым приложением Win32. Это не связано с этой ошибкой ??

Comment: Не надо файлы переименовывать, вы так вообще все превратите в кашу. Смотрите настройки проекта, и обратите внимание на скриптовые переменные, про которые вам написано. Сообщения об ошибках надо читать очень внимательно, там все по существу. `lua53` это исходное имя проекта, его изменить возможно, но очень непросто. Лучше стройте `lua53.dll`, а потом переименовывайте.

Comment: @freim спасибо большое за ответ. Еще бы знать как это все теперь реализовать и где находятся эти настройки.

Comment: Правой кнопкой на проекте в окне Solution Explorer, и выбираете Properties.